# Join multiple tables rails sql query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

```
class Account
 has_many :metadata

class Keys
 has_many :metadata

class Metadatum
 belongs_to :key
 belongs_ to :account
```

In Metadatum object I keep additional information about Account, for exapmle 'age'.

In Key object I keep information about type of Metadatum.

Metadatum table:

- id
- key_id
- account_id
- value

Key table:

- name
- data_type

I want to search accounts by multiple metadata. For example

- Metadatum with value = '18' that belongs to Key with name = 'age'
- Metadatum with value = 'John' that belongs to Key with name = 'first_name'

My query is:

```
    accounts.joins(metadata: :key).where("keys.name = ? AND 
    metadata.value = ?", params[:key], params[:value]).where("keys.name 
    = ? AND metadata.value = ?", params[:key1], params[:value1])
```

It is wrong because in my opinion it looks for an Account that has Metadatum with both key_ids and values. No such Metadatum exists - each has only one key_id and value.

What would be the right query?

Answer (score 1):

If you want accounts that comply with both conditions, I would try:

```
first = Account.joins(metadata: :key).where("keys.name = ? AND metadata.value = ?", params[:key], params[:value])

final = first.joins(metadata : :key).where("keys.name 
= ? AND metadata.value = ?", params[:key1], params[:value1])
```

**New try (really ugly :))**

```
first_ids = Account.joins(metadata: :key).where("keys.name = ? AND metadata.value = ?", params[:key], params[:value]).pluck(“accounts.id”)

final = Account.where(id: first_ids).joins(metadata : :key).where("keys.name = ? AND metadata.value = ?", params[:key1], params[:value1])
```

Comment: Below is the sql query that I have. Still does not show me accounts that has both metadata

Comment: SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" INNER JOIN "metadata" ON "metadata"."account_id" = "accounts"."id" AND "metadata"."deleted_at" IS NULL INNER JOIN "keys" ON "keys"."id" = "metadata"."key_id" AND "keys"."deleted_at" IS NULL WHERE "accounts"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (keys.name = 'first_name' AND metadata.value = 'Robert') AND (keys.name = 'age' AND metadata.value = '18')

Comment: I tried a second approach. I don't like it, but it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
accounts.joins(metadata: :key)
        .where("(keys.name = ? AND metadata.value = ?) OR 
                (keys.name = ? AND metadata.value = ?)",  
         params[:key], params[:value], params[:key1], params[:value1])
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I want, because If I search for "John"(metadata1) that is "18"(metadata2) years old I will also receive all NOT"Johns" that are "18" and all "Johns" that are NOT"18"

Comment: Nope in that case your query should be only `accounts.joins(metadata: :key).where("(keys.name = ? AND metadata.value = ?)",  params[:key], params[:value])`

Comment: You have to generate dynamic queries depending on the parameters